# Mapping models From Angular to asp.net core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

i am trying to figure the best way to map a model from angular to asp.net core API and vice versa!

for example :

in API model

```
int id {get;set;}
string name {get;set;}
```

what should i put in my angular model file ?

should i use a ViewModel then map it? if yes , please give an example ... thanks

Comment: Create an interface to represent the model. `interface MyModel { id: number; name: string }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose if you have a C# model like below which you are sending over API calls,

```
public class Student{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

and you are sending the same in JSON format like below

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"john"
}
```

you can use define an interface (or class in case you want to write some methods in it) like below

name : student.modal.ts

```
export interface Student{
      id: number,
      name:string
}
```

Comment: It should be `export interface Student { ... }`

Comment: is using interface different from using class ?

Comment: @NicholasK correct

Comment: @OmarSawy When you want to define only types and no member methods, using interface is a good practice.